representing refer to?
Source: McMinn's Clinical Atlas of Human Anatomy

In fat people, the bladder may lie far cranially, with a long, thin soft tissue band extending
to the pubis, representing the urethra.

what does ''representing'' in this sentence refer to. ?

I'm puzzled by cranially, as the only definition I can find for cranial is 'related to the skull'! Presumably they mean that the urethra looks like a long thin band in these people.

@KateBunting in anatomy, "cranially" just means something is oriented towards the cranium. The problem with prepositions like "above" or "below" in anatomy is that they are relative to whether the organism is bipedal or quadrupedal.

This is clearly specialist anatomical language (does it really use "fat", I'd have expected "obese" or something more medical)  You would probably get better answers on a specialised site like [medicalsciences.se]

@JamesK The OP cites a technical book on anatomy. Why change that? Fat is fat in English, not thin, not slim. fat aka adipose

I don't want to "change it".  I'm merely surprised that the book uses "fat" to describe people, instead of "obese" or "adipose".  Normally these books don't use such simple words as "fat", especially when that word has a lot of cultural baggage.

In anatomical terms, "representing" typically refers to a structure or organ that stands for or symbolizes another structure or organ.
In this context, it is describing how far the tissue band from the bladder extends - it extends as far as the pubis (the pair of bones forming the two sides of the pelvis). However, this tissue itself is not the pelvis - it is the urethra.

OP's sentence is:

In fat people, the bladder may lie far cranially, with a long, thin soft tissue band extending to the pubis, representing the urethra.

To fully understand this sentence, one should be familiar with human anatomy.
Alternatively, look at the  word's meanings in a dictionary
Ref. Cambridge dictionary:

1.bladder= urinary bladder
2.Cranially= related to skull
3.Pubis= one of the three main bones of the pelvis.
4.Urethra = the tube in most mammals that carries urine from the bladder out of the body.
5.represent = to speak, act, or be present officially for another person or people:

Here  "representing" means a long thin soft tissue represents the urethra.
"Bladder to the pubis is where the urethra is located. It carries the urine from the bladder to be thrown out of the body.
In simple words it means:
"In fat people, the bladder may move upwards. Due to the excess fat tissues, the urethra may not be directly visible, but a long, thin soft tissue band indicates the location of the urethra."
